# Помогите решить задачу с рекуррентной формулой

Tags: c++

Есть задание "Написать прграмму вычисления числа сочетаний из `m` элементов по

`n (n<=m) Cnm=m!/n!(m-n)!`,

Где m и n вводятся с клавиатуры, используя рекуррентную формулу

`Cm0=1, Cnm=m-n+1/n * Cmn-1`"

То что получилось:

```
#include <iostream> // Добавление библиотеки ввода-вывода
#include <math.h> // Добавление библиотеки математических функций
#include <stdio.h> // Добавление библиотеки стандартного ввода-вывода
#include <conio.h> // Добавление библиотеки для создания текстового интерфейса пользователя 
#include <windows.h> // Добавление библиотеки стандартных функци
#include <string> // Добавление библиотеки для работы со строками

using namespace std; // Использование пространства имен std

double soch(int n, int m) { // Рекурсивная функция для рассчета числа сочетаний
    if (n==0 || m==n)
    { // Если n = 0 или т == n
        return 1; // Возвращяем единицу
    }
    else
    { // В остальных случаях рачитываем по формуле
        return soch(n-1,m-1)+soch(n,m-1); // Рекуррентная формула для числа сочетаний возращает полученое значение после рекурсии
    }

}

int main() // Главная функция
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251); // Установка кодировки консоли на ввод
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // Установка кодировки консоли на вывод
    int m; // Объявление переменной для хранения количества числа m
    int n; // Объявление переменной для хранения количества числа n

    do { // Цикл проверки правильности ввода чисел m и n
        cout << "Введите число m которое =>n" << endl; // Вывод уведомления о вводе числа m
        cin >> m; // Ввод числа m
        cout << "Введите число n которое <=m" << endl; // Вывод уведомления о вводе числа n 
        cin >> n; // Ввод числа 
        if (m<n){ // Проверка правильности ввода чисел для вывода уведомления
            cout << "Неверно введены числа: m < n. Введите числа так, чтобы было m => n" << endl; // Уведомление о введении неверных чисел
        }
    } while (m<n); // Проверяем условие что m=>n, если введены неверные числа повтораяем ввод

    cout << "Число сочетаний = " << soch(n,m); // Выводим число сочетаний путем передачи в функцию введеных чисел m и n
    _getch(); // Ожидаем нажатия кнопки
    return 0; // Конец программы
}
```

Comment: Но как мне сказали формула не реальзована... Не пойму что не так...

Comment: в целом вроде всё верно, вы используете для расчета рекуррентную формулу числа сочетаний, также можно вместо рекуррентной формулы числа сочетаний реализовать функцию вычисления факториала и считать с его помощью по обычной формуле, но это тоже самое

Comment: а кто вам сказал про формулу?

Comment: препод сказал что формула не реализована

Comment: Что вот эта формула не реализована Cnm=m-n+1/n * Cmn-1

Comment: Надо было сказать "Вот жеш она" и показать пальцем на строку `return soch(n-1,m-1)+soch(n,m-1);`

Comment: Извините, я не вдупляю в формулу, C(n,m) = C(n-1,m-1) + C(n, m-1) - это валидная рекуррентная формула, вы её реализовали. Что такое  Cnm=m-n+1/n * Cmn-1?

Comment: в задании написано умножение... до этого и докопался препод... что в проге идет сложение а по заданию в формуле умножение стоит но при попытке заменить сложение на умножение прога работать не хочет. вот и ломаю голову. Что такое рекуррентная формула и почему я ее реальзовал не правильно если везже всегда делают так

Comment: Александр, рекуррентная формула - это формула, которая вызывает сама себя, т.е. использует рекурсию.Для числа сочетаний корректной является формула C(n,m) = C(n-1,m-1) + C(n, m-1), ваша программа правильная. Возможно существует другая рекуррентная формула для вычисления числа сочетаний, но это  Cnm=m-n+1/n * Cmn-1 не она

Comment: C:=1;
  for i:=1 to N do
    C:=((M-i+1) div i)*C;
вот аналогичное решение только не помню на паскале. не пойму как перевести в свое

Comment: @goldstar_labs, реализация рекуррентной формулы не обязательно использует рекурсию.

Comment: @АлександрИванов, перевел ваше решение на C: `int C = 1; \ for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++) \ C *= (M - i+1) / i;`.